# ConstraintLayout, TextView and ImageView with Horizontal Alignment and Auto Sizing

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have been facing a problem and believe it is a set of multiple incorrect positioning choices, some information before:

1 - Drawable image has larger width and height than it fits.
2 - TextView text is dynamic but it should never be more than one line, if it is more than one line it should be "cut".

I have the following code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/icon"
            android:text="my small text"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/icon"
            android:text="description text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/description"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_print"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Some explanations: As the image is very large and I need it positioned to the left I use **android:scaleType="fitEnd"** and **android:padding="8dp"**.

The result is satisfactory:

[image]

Problem:

**When I put very large text in my title I would like it to "push" ImageView to its limit when it is actually limiting itself to 50%.**

[image]

It's like my ImageView has a "fixed" width when I'm actually using "match contraints with 0dp"

I already tried to add app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" to id: title and id: description (unsuccessfully)

Comment: Take a look at barriers in constraint layout

Comment: @RohitSuthar I will

Answer (score 1):

Add a guideline and constrain your title instead of constraining it to the icon. That way when it reaches the guideline it will stop increasing and the icon that’s still constrained to the title will keep its minimum space. The ellipsize property will add the dots at the end of the title when it gets too big. All you need to do is decide what the minimum space is going to be for your icon, by adjusting the percentage on the guideline.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="my small text"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="description text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_print"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/description"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/title" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT after clarification in comments:
This is the proposed Barrier solution.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="my small text"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="description text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/description"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/title" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="start"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="icon" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I believe something is wrong. The text overwrote guideline and did not apply the EndToStart limit. And I can't keep adjusting guideline based on ImageView (the icons are also dynamic and will run in various resolutions)

Comment: @Jonny I misunderstood. If the images need to be more dynamic as well, I second the barriers as suggested by Rohit

Comment: @Jonny Which view gets priority, the text or the icon? Which gets its size adjusted first? Do you want the original image and then check the remaining space and adjust the text accordingly, the other way around or some combination of the two?

Comment: Text has priority as low as possible occupied by the image (wrap content). The text is on the left, the image on the right. That is, if I have large text, it would be displayed until the minimum width for the image to appear.

Comment: I got it, added app:layout_constrainedHeight="true" to the description (used as a height reference constraint) and changed image to android:layout_width = "wrap_content" and kept only app:layout_constrainedHeight= true" in it. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Great i will try out.

Comment: @Jonny I'm glad you got it working. If you get to try my new solution as well, I'd be interested to find out if it does what you want